# Use GROUPY BY to get the name and price of its most expensive product

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE Manufacturers (
    Code          integer PRIMARY KEY,
    Name          text
);
CREATE TABLE Products (
    Code          integer PRIMARY KEY,
    Name          text,
    Price         real,
    Manufacturer  integer REFERENCES Manufacturers (Code)
);
```

I want select the name of each manufacturer along with the name and price of its most expensive product.

I try this in Postgresql9.6

```
SELECT A.Name, A.Price, F.Name
    FROM Products A INNER JOIN Manufacturers F
    ON A.Manufacturer = F.Code
    AND A.Price =
    (
      SELECT MAX(A.Price)
      FROM Products A
      WHERE A.Manufacturer = F.Code
    );
```

It takes like forever to finish it.

Then I try this:

```
SELECT Manufacturers.Name AS ManufacturersName, MAX(Price), Products.Name
  FROM Products, Manufacturers
  WHERE Products.Manufacturer = Manufacturers.Code
  GROUP BY Manufacturers.Name;
```

I got ERROR:

```
ERROR:  column "products.name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: ...ufacturers.Name AS ManufacturersName, MAX(Price), Products.N...
```

I know products.name should not appear in it, but is it postgresql's constraint?

I need products.name in result, could someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

The following query will give the most expensive price for each manufacturer product.  It will return multiple products in the event of a tie.  If you just want one product per manufacturer regardless of a tie, replace `DENSE_RANK` with `ROW_NUMBER`.

```
SELECT
    t.m_name,
    t.p_name,
    t.Price
FROM
(
    SELECT
        t1.Name AS m_name,
        COALESCE(t2.Name, 'NA') AS p_name,
        COALESCE(t2.Price, 0.0) AS price,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.Code ORDER BY t2.Price DESC) dr
    FROM Manufacturers t1
    LEFT JOIN Products t2
        ON t1.Code = t2.Manufacturer
) t
WHERE t.dr = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (m.Name) m.Name AS ManufacturersName, p.Price, p.Name
FROM Products p JOIN
     Manufacturers m
     ON p.Manufacturer = m.Code
ORDER BY m.Name, p.Price DESC;
```

No aggregation would appear to be necessary.